# How to get a request parameter from URL in JSF 1.2?

Tags: spring, jsf

I have a Spring + JSF 1.2 application which sends an email with a link to the user after subscription. The link contains a request parameter like:

> www.myapp.com/register.jsf?var=1

How can I get this request parameter in my JSF backing bean?

Comment: You might need to share some code to show where you're up to before anyone can help.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear if you're using Spring or JSF to manage your beans, but in standard JSF 1.2, you need to register it as `<managed-property>` of the `<managed-bean>` with a value of `#{param.var}` where `var` is the exact request parameter name:

```
<managed-bean>
    ...
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>var</property-name>
        <value>#{param.var}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

So if your bean has a property

```
private String var; // +setter (getter is not mandatory)
```

then you can access and process it in a `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("var is: " + var);
}
```

---

As a completely different alternative, you can also obtain it directly from the request parameter:

```
String var = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("var");
// ...
```

Comment: Thank's Alex and BalusC for you answers.

Well, i used in my controller session scope, the methode getRequestParameterMap.get("var") but i always get var = NULL, I called the requestParameter methode from my constructor, because it seems to me it's the only place to get my value. But as i said, when i transform my controller into a singleton scope it works, the requesteParameter treurns 1 for var, but i couldn't call any of my services form that singleton controller :(

Comment: The constructor of a session scoped bean is only called when the session is started, not when the HTTP request is made. Make the bean request scoped instead.

Comment: Hi balusC, i am still stick on this :(, when i make my managed bean requested scope, i have the same probeleme with singeleton scope. I just can't call any of my DAO Methodes. I call my services using @Ressource cause i am in Spring structure.